# AJAX won't POST to PHP (Non jQuery)

Tags: php, ajax, function, post

I've searched and search and all I find is jQuery questions and fixes for this. I have one script setup that works fine but this one will not post post the 3 values to the php script. I've even tried to force feed 3 set values into where I'm putting the timestamp and that dosn't work. I'm at a bit of a loss.

This script generates different fields/inputs to run updateCoupon()

```
        function updateForm(formNum,id){
            var str = 'edit-contents'+id;
            switch( formNum )
            {
                case 1:
                    document.getElementById(str).innerHTML = "<div class='title-input'>Promo Title:<br><input type='text' size='25' maxlength='100' id='ptitle' name='ptitle'><input name='Edit' type='button' class='EditCoup' id='EditCoup' value='Edit' onClick='javascript:updateCoupon("+id+",1);'></div>";
                    break;

                case 2:
                    document.getElementById(str).innerHTML = "<div class='description-input'>Promo Description:<br><textarea maxlength='1256' cols='40' rows='5' id='pdescription' placeholder='Use <br> to insert a line break' name='pdescription'></textarea><input name='Edit' type='button' class='EditCoup' id='EditCoup'  value='Edit' onClick='javascript:updateCoupon("+id+",2);'></div>";
                    break;

                case 3:
                    document.getElementById(str).innerHTML = "<div class='Disclaimer-input'>Promo Disclaimer:<br><textarea maxlength='1256' cols='40' rows='5' id='pdisclaimer' placeholder='Use <br> to insert a line break' name='pdisclaimer'></textarea><input name='Edit' type='button' class='EditCoup' id='EditCoup' value='Edit' onClick='javascript:updateCoupon("+id+",3);'></div>";
                    break;

                case 4:
                    document.getElementById(str).innerHTML = "<div class='expDate'>Promo Experation:<br><input type='text' size='25' maxlength='100' id='datepicker'  placeholder='DD-MM-YYYY' name='datepicker'><input name='Edit' type='button' class='EditCoup' id='EditCoup' value='Edit' onClick='javascript:updateCoupon("+id+",4);'></div>";
                    break;

                case 5:
                    document.getElementById(str).innerHTML = "<div class='image-input'>Select a Promo Image:<br><select id='picture' name='picture'><option value='' Selected>Select Image...</option><option value='http://cws.dealerconnection.com/images/MAX.png'>Battery MAX</option><option value='http://cws.dealerconnection.com/images/PLUS.png'>Battery MAX</option><option value='http://cws.dealerconnection.com/images/brake.gif'>Brakes</option><option value='http://cws.dealerconnection.com/images/checkup.png'>Check List</option><option value='http://cws.dealerconnection.com/images/CreditCards.gif'>Ford Credit Card</option><option value='http://cws.dealerconnection.com/images/lptg.png'>Low Price Tire Gaurentee</option><option value='http://cws.dealerconnection.com/images/michelin.gif'>Michelin</option><option value='http://cws.dealerconnection.com/images/works.png'>The Works</option><option value='http://cws.dealerconnection.com/images/4tires.gif'>Tires</option><option value='http://cws.dealerconnection.com/images/TR99.png'>Tire Brand Logos</option><option value='http://cws.dealerconnection.com/images/wipers.png'>Wiper Blades</option><option value='http://cws.dealerconnection.com/images/Fpseal.png'>Warranty Ford Parts</option><option value='http://cws.dealerconnection.com/images/Mcseal.png'>Warranty Motocraft</option></select><input name='Edit' type='button' class='EditCoup' id='EditCoup' value='Edit' onClick='javascript:updateCoupon("+id+",5';'></div>";
                    break;

                default:
                    alert("Error:"+formNum);
                break;
            }
        }
        </script>
```

AJAX:

```
        var xmlhttp = '';

        function createXMLHttpRequest() {
          if (window.ActiveXObject) { xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); } 
          else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); }
        }

        function updateCoupon(id,field)
        {

            var tempId = id;

            switch( field )
            {
                case '1':
                    var updateField = "headline";
                    var title = form.ptitle.value;
                    var queryStr = "id=" + tempId + "&change=" + title + "&field=" +updateField;
                    break;

                case '2':
                    var updateField = "subhead";
                    var desc = form.pdescription.value;
                    var queryStr = "id=" + tempId + "&change=" + desc + "&field=" +updateField;
                    break;

                case '3':
                    var updateField = "disclaimer";
                    var disc = form.pdisclaimer.value;
                    var queryStr = "id=" + tempId + "&change=" + disc + "&field=" +updateField;
                    break;

                case '4':
                    var updateField = "couponexpires";
                    var date = form.datepicker.value;
                    var queryStr = "id=" + tempId + "&change=" + date + "&field=" +updateField;
                    break;

                case '5':           
                    var updateField = "graphics";
                    var pic = form.picture.value;
                    var queryStr = "id=" + tempId + "&change=" + pic + "&field=" +updateField;
                    break;
            }

                createXMLHttpRequest();

              var url = "/coupon_testing/Ford_coupon_tool/php/couponEdit.php?timeStamp=" + new Date().getTime();
              xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
              xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                    if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        var jResponse = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        if(jResponse != '')  {
                            alert(jResponse);
                        }
                    }
                  } 
              };

              xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");   
              xmlhttp.send(queryStr);
        }
```

PHP:

```
        <?php
            $ret = "Error";
            $id = $_POST['id'];
            $change = trim($_POST['change']);
            $field = trim($_POST['field']);

            include 'configuration.inc.php';
            include 'connection.inc.php';
            include 'db_functions.inc.php';
        //set variables from the coupon setup form

            if( $id != '' && $change != '' && $field != '' )
            {
                //Saving the coupon to the database.
                $sql = "UPDATE ford_coupons SET " . $field . "='" . addslashes($change)."' WHERE id='".addslashes($id)."' LIMIT 1";
                execute_query($sql);
                $ret = $field." has been updated!";
            }
            // print $ret;
            $str = "id=".$id.", change=".$change.", field=".$field;
            print $str;
        ?>
```

Can anyone tell me what the issue is here? been racking my brain and that of another programmer friend and neither of us know why it is not posting. Thanks

Comment: Do you see anything happening in JS console? any requests, any errors?
Also, how are you calling 'updateCoupon(id,field)'? please show some more sample code...

Comment: knew I forgot a snippet! Sorry about that, I've updated it with the js that creates the inputs and button to send the field and id to the updateCoupon().

There are no errors being generated anywhere, the timestamp is showing up in firebug just fine. The alert test (within the php) is popping up with id=, change=, field=,

Comment: try to add the following header: xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", queryStr.length);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close"); after the content-type

Comment: Added that and it can't find length of undefined so it seems that the case isn't being triggered to set queryStr... hmm

Comment: or you're passing an int to the function and not the string.... cause your switch is comparing '1' not 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling updateCoupon(id,field) using numeric values, like this

```
javascript:updateCoupon("+id+",1);
```

But in your switch statement, you're only checking for string values, like this

```
case '1':
```

You need to either call the functions using a string for the 'field' argument, or change your cases to use integers.

During execution, none of the switch statements will get hit, hence the empty AJAX request...